# Can EMT conduit have holes?

Tags: wiring, conduit

The previous owner left eight 10' sections of 3/4" EMT, but he drilled holes through every one of them (a hole every 18-24" or so).  Can this still be used to route wire indoors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations. You have a bunch of 18-24" chunks of 3/4" conduit. You do not have 10 foot chunks of conduit. Unless you have mechanical plans (I've seen folks do small greenhouses with conduit) might as well cut them at the holes.

Comment: That's what I figured (too good to be true).  Do you know the rationale behind this?  My guess is dust etc. can get in through the holes and create a fire hazard.

Comment: they should have exactly two holes in each piece.... one in each tube end (humor)

Comment: Also insulation damage - holes have burrs which can be sharp.